# Undefined index in php array when using $matches[0] in preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace-callback

I am trying to replace instances of breve characters with caron in some older web pages containing hanyu pinyin, one of the Mandarin Chinese phonetic systems. (FYI, "breve" characters have a u shaped diacritical mark and "caron" characters have a v shaped diacritical mark)

```
$content = 'băd cĕf tĭl gŏŭ';
echo preg_replace_callback ( '/[ăĕĭŏŭ]/', function ($match) {
    $b2c = array(
    "ă"=>"ǎ", 
    "ĕ"=>"ě", 
    "ĭ"=>"ǐ",
    "ŏ"=>"ǒ", 
    "ŭ"=>"ǔ");
    $letter = $match[0];
    return $b2c[$letter];
}, $content);
```

When I use "return $letter", I get the breve letters. And when I call $b2c["ă"], it returns the correct coran letter.  So I suspect that $match[0] is not actually a character, but, after rummaging through the doc pages I could find nothing to substantiate that theory.

BTW, I found that str_replace works better than preg_replace for this particular problem, but, for future reference, I would still like to know why the code above does not work.